# Building site map with html, for user site navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation, navbar

I want to build an navigation bar in a website, so that the user will know where he is in the site, and easily can go back to the previous element (NOT the regular bootstrap navbar, another one underneath it). For example:
I want the user to see:
Home > Products > Softwere > Antivirus
So the user can see where he is and how he got there, and can go back to the previous category.
I can do that the "dumb" way, and just add dev with buttens that redirect back to the pages I want, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way to connect the DOM elments so that the navigation bar will automaticly connect them and present them on the navigation bar.
Does anyone have idea how to approuch this problem?
Thanks,
Yishai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I think your are looking for dynamic breadcrumbs](http://www.javascriptsource.com/navigation/automatic-breadcrumbs.html)

Check above link

Comment: The above link will help you.

Comment: let me know the above link is useful or not?

Comment: looks like the closest thing I have to what I'm looking for. Thanks!